# Shared folder/Centralized folder location to get reports for 2 Azure VMs

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I currently have this web-farm setup where there's a load balancer, Server 1 and Server 2 that has the web site hosted via IIS.

Here's the scenario: A user accesses our site, the load balancer puts him into Server 1 and uses the report generation feature, which saves the report file on the server. The file is now saved at Server 1 and you can download it there. The problem is when the user accesses our site again and if the load balancer puts him on Server 2 and tries to download the generated report it will obviously not find the file as the file is stored on Server 1.

I've researched some ways and find some solutions to make them upload/download to a cloud service but in that way the process and wait time became long. I can do FTP transfer but I would like it as my last option. Can anyone suggest some methods for this set-up?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you simply attach a data drive to the VM and set it up as a shared drive. That way no matter which user is logged into any VM the drive will be there.

You could also just create a storage account and map the drives to both VMs as well.